# How to inject wcf proxy using spring .net

Tags: .net, wcf, spring.net

I'm new to Spring.Net.
I have one wcf service class which needs the proxy of another service like:

```
[ServiceContract]
Interface IService1{
  [OperationContract]
  void show();

}

[ServiceContract]
Interface IService2{
  [OperationContract]
  void show();

}
class Service1:IService1
{
  public IService2 Service2
  {
    get;set;
  }

  public void Show()
  {
    Service2.Show();
  }
}
```

How do I inject the proxy of service2 inside the Service1 proxy by configuring it in App.config file in Spring.Net?

App.config file
@bbai  Please find the below app.config file.  ServiceHost im creating inside my Program.cs file.

```
<sectionGroup name="spring">
  <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
  <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

```
  <object id="Service1Obj" singleton="false"
               type="MyNamespace.Service1, MyAssembly">
    <!-- Setter injection-->
    <property name="Service2" ref="Service2"/>
  </object>

  <object id="Service2Obj" singleton="false"
         type="MyNamespace.Service2, MyAssembly">
  </object>

  <!-- Creating Client side proxy dynamically-->
  <object id="Service1"
    type="MyNamespace.IService1, MyAssembly"
    factory-object="Service1ChannelFactory"
    factory-method="CreateChannel" />

  <object id="Service1ChannelFactory"
      type="System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory&lt;MyNamespace.IService1>, System.ServiceModel">
    <constructor-arg name="endpointConfigurationName" value="Service1Endpoint" />
  </object>

  <object id="Service2"
    type="MyNamespace.IService2, MyAssembly"
    factory-object="Service2ChannelFactory"
    factory-method="CreateChannel" />

  <object id="Service2ChannelFactory"
      type="System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory&lt;MyNamespace.IService2>, System.ServiceModel">
    <constructor-arg name="endpointConfigurationName" value="Service2Endpoint" />
  </object>
</objects>
```

```
  <service name="Service2Obj" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="MyNamespace.IService2" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <!--<endpoint name="serverWebCalculatorEndpoint" address="http://localhost:2637/Spring.WcfQuickStart.ServerWeb/Calculator.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding1" contract="Spring.WcfQuickStart.ICalculator"/>-->
  <endpoint name="Service1Endpoint" address="http://localhost:8000" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyNamespace.IService1"/>
  <endpoint name="Service2Endpoint" address="http://localhost:8001" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyNamespace.IService2"/>
</client>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:wcf="http://www.springframework.net/wcf">

  <!-- Service2 proxy -->
  <wcf:channelFactory id="Service2"
       channelType="MyNamespace.IService2, MyAssembly"
       endpointConfigurationName="Service2Endpoint" />

  <!-- Service 1 -->
  <object id="Service1" type="MyNamespace.Service1, MyAssembly" singleton="false">
    <property name="Service2" ref="Service2" />
  </object>

</objects>
```

More documentation here : http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html

Comment: @bbaia   Hi, I have tried the mentioned solution but still im getting null refrence exception. Inside the Service1.Show() service2 instance is null.what i did is like from Aplication context got the service1 instance and then when i called Service1.Show() that time service2 is null.                                                           Here Service1 is also a proxy.Its like injecting a proxy inside another proxy.

Comment: share your configuration sample.

Comment: @bbai : hi, i have shared my config file.Please go through it.

Comment: How do you host your services ? 
Using a .svc file or using the SpringServiceHost ?

Comment: @bbai :im hosting as follows ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyNamespace.Service1)); host .AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyNamespace.IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000"); host .Open();

Comment: @bbai : i tried to configure in app.config as  <object id="calculatorServiceHost" type="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryObject, Spring.Services">
        <property name="TargetName" value="Service1Obj" />
      </object>       By doing like this im getting one execption as cannot load assemby  Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryObject from Spring.Services

Comment: Don't use ServiceHost, use SpringServiceHost :
SpringServiceHost host = new SpringServiceHost("Service1Obj");
instead of
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyNamespace.Service1));

Comment: @bbai: If i use SpringServiceHost to host the services do i need to configure it in App.config or shall i host it inside Program.cs using SpringServiceHost ang AddServiceEndpoint to it. Second doubt is when to close the Hosted services.

Comment: Just use SpringServiceHost as you should use ServiceHost. The only difference is the spring object id in parameter instead of the type.

Comment: @bbai: Thank you very much for the help.Now the code is working properly.

Comment: If this answer was most helpful to you, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This way, everybody knows your problem was solved. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

Using IoC in WCF isn't straightforward, but in this case you can use an `IInstanceProvider` to resolve the reference to IService2 when the service is being created. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx has an example of using that interface to implement a simple IoC container for a WCF service.

Comment: Hi, i wanted to use only the spring .net. Im new to sprin.net.if you have any solution by using spring .net please tel me.

Comment: @bbaia   Hi, I have tried the mentioned solution but still im getting null refrence exception. Inside the Service1.Show() service2 instance is null.what i did is like from Aplication context got the service1 instance and then when i called Service1.Show() that time service2 is null.                                                           Here Service1 is also a proxy.Its like injecting a proxy inside another proxy.